# wordpress custom post type slugs and rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have 2 custom post types in my wordpress site,

```
 // Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'properties',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Properties' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Property' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

and

```
 // Our custom post type function
function create_team_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'team',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Team Members' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Team Member' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'our-team'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
 
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_team_posttype' );
```

When I go to `mydomain.com/properties` I see my `archive-properties.php` page template I see the correct template and content. I have a team archive teamplate called `archive-team.php` but but when I go to it's URl `mydomain.com/our-team` I see the `archive-properties.php` template am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass an argument for the archive slug. Currently, you are only passing the slug for the single custom post. So your custom posts are now at /our-team/some-team-slug

If you want to modify your archive, you'll need to use:

```
$args = array(
  'has_archive' => 'our-team',
);
```

In the codex it is explained as [follows](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/):

'has_archive'
(bool|string) Whether there should be post type archives, or if a string, the archive slug to use. Will generate the proper rewrite rules if $rewrite is enabled. Default false.

You might need to rewrite your permalinks or unregister and re-register your custom post type to be sure the change gets picked up.